# JSON format inside record in csv file - convert to column Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dataframe, csv

This is my data. Inside the column - 'device' and 'geonetwork' store the data as a dict or json format. I would like to create new columns based on data from that columns, fore example -> new column should be 'browser','browserversion', 'continent' and so on. I have tried a lot of solutions, but it dosen't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00dqM.png)

DATA

,date,device,fullVisitorId,geoNetwork
0,20180420,"{""browser"": ""Chrome"", ""browserVersion"": ""not available in demo dataset"", ""browserSize"": ""not available in demo dataset"", ""operatingSystem"": ""Macintosh""}",3.37108036201195E+018,"{""continent"": ""Americas"", ""subContinent"": ""Northern America"", ""country"": ""United States"", ""region"": ""California""}"
1,20180328,"{""browser"": ""Chrome"", ""browserVersion"": ""not available in demo dataset"",
""browserSize"": ""not available in demo dataset"", ""operatingSystem"": ""Macintosh""}",1.27350339266773E+018,"{""continent"": ""Americas"", ""subContinent"": ""Northern America"", ""country"": ""Canada"", ""region"": ""State of Sao Paulo""}"

A little help how to solve my problem

Comment: Python has a module "json" for converting JSON to Python data structures. Just iterate through the CSV-rows, convert the JSON, extract the desired data and add it to the row. Where exactly is the problem? Show your try as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: I know how to convert this csv file to json file, but I do not know how to retrieve the data from "device" column and then add the 'key'  of this data as a new column.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bzf3.png)

On the attached picture first new column name is highlited. It is json file

```
import csv
import json


def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for row in csvReader:
            jsonArray.append(row)

    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)


csvFilePath = r'dane.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```